# Azure Pipelines - Constantly getting ModuleNotFoundError despite installing dependencies

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am trying to run a python script as part of an ADO pipeline. The first job installs pandas and runs successfully. However, the second job fails because it says I have not installed pandas (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`), despite having done so already.

Here is the YAML configuration:

```
stages:
- stage: scrape_text
  jobs:
  - job: InstallPackages
    displayName: 'Install packages'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '3.9'
          addToPath: true
      - script: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python -m pip install pandas
        displayName: 'Install dependencies'

  - job: RunScript
    displayName: 'Scrape text'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    dependsOn: InstallPackages
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.9'
        addToPath: true
    - task: PythonScript@0
      displayName: 'Run scraper script'
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'filePath'
        scriptPath: 'path/to/text_scrapper.py'
```

I tried specifying the python version in both jobs as well as the vmImage, but they all still show the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging, I realized that it's because the dependencies I installed in the first job are not carried over to the second job. I resolved the issue by just combining both jobs into one and it worked.